# Reading from a file, C++ conversion: string to int beginner question

Tags: c++, arrays, type-conversion, ifstream

can anyone help/advise me with the best way to go about converting the variable scodeID into an integer within this code.  Any tips or hints would be really appreciated to help me improve my skills.  I have pasted all my code below so you can see what I am working with.  The variable I need to convert to an int is when I am using the setter method to send the variable up to the method as a call by copy (the variable i need to convert is inside the while loop in main).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class cSquare { //declares a new class called cSquare
public: //declares all members as public
string SquareName; //first and only member of the cSquare class called square name
int cost;
int rent;
int codeID;
int colourGroup;
//get and set methods
void setSquareName(string); //class method to input into the variable SquareName
void setcost(int);
void setrent(int);
void setcodeID(int codeID);
void setcolourGroup(int);
string getSquareName() const; //class method to output the contents of SquareName
int getcost() const;
int getrent() const;
int getcodeID() const;
int getcolourGroup() const;

friend istream & operator >> (istream & is, cSquare & s); //sets a friend to allow 
the use of >>

};

// square name set method

void cSquare::setcodeID(int scodeID)
{
codeID = scodeID;
}

void cSquare::setSquareName(string sname)
{
SquareName = sname;
}

void cSquare::setcost(int scost)
{
cost = scost;
}
void cSquare::setrent(int srent)
{
rent = srent;
}

void cSquare::setcolourGroup(int scolourGroup)
{
colourGroup = scolourGroup;
}

//square name get method
string cSquare::getSquareName() const
{
return SquareName;
}

int cSquare::getcost() const
{
return cost;
}
int cSquare::getrent() const
{
return rent;
}
int cSquare::getcodeID() const
{
return codeID;
}
int cSquare::getcolourGroup() const
{
return colourGroup;
}


ostream & operator << (ostream & os, const cSquare & s)
{
os << s.getSquareName() << ' '
    << s.getcost() << ' '
    << s.getrent() << ' '
    << s.getcodeID() << ' '
    << s.getcolourGroup();
return os;
}

istream & operator >> (istream & is, cSquare & s)
{
is >> s.SquareName >> s.cost >> s.rent >> s.codeID >> s.colourGroup;
return is;
}


int main()
{
string discard;
int i = 0; //counter
const int MAX_SIZE = 26; //declares a constant to store the size of the array - this 
will not chance so it is ok to be a const
ifstream monopoly("monopoly.txt", ios::in); //reads file in as a read only file
if (monopoly.is_open()) //checks if the file is open
{
    cSquare myArray[MAX_SIZE]; //declares the array of the object cSquare class

    getline(monopoly, discard); //allows it to be read line by line 
    string sname; //string to store what I read in from my file
    string scost;
    string srent;   
    string codeID;
    string scolourGroup;
    

    while (i < MAX_SIZE && monopoly >> codeID >> sname >> scost >> srent >> 
scolourGroup) //inputs the contents of the file into the string sname
    {       
        myArray[i].setcodeID(scodeID);//stores the string read in into the array
        myArray[i].setSquareName(sname);//stores the string read in into the array
        myArray[i].setcost(scost);//stores the string read in into the array
        myArray[i].setrent(srent);//stores the string read in into the array
        myArray[i].setcolourGroup(scolourGroup);//stores the string read in into the 
 array

        cout << myArray[i].getcodeID(); //it outputs what is stored in the array 
here
        cout << myArray[i].getSquareName(); //it outputs what is stored in the array 
here
        cout << myArray[i].getcost(); //it outputs what is stored in the array here
        cout << myArray[i].getrent(); //it outputs what is stored in the array here
        cout << myArray[i].getcolourGroup(); //it outputs what is stored in the 
array here
        i++; //adds one each time to the i counter
    }

}
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code ... You can use [`std::strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) or `instream >> integer_variable;` to read it directly from the stream into an integer variable.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Any specific reason for recommending `std::strtol` over `std::strtoi`? Is there a reason to prefer `long` over `int`? Doesn't seem like the differences come into play unless you're on a 16-bit system or something along those lines.

Comment: @sweenish Nope, no reason. `strtoi` is probably perfectly ok. I can't find it though.

Comment: @sweenish, There's no `strtoi` in the standard.

Comment: @chris Typo on my end. `std::stoi` is what I was after. This is where I express disdain at the Standard Library for allowing so many variations (with their varying coverage) on the same thing to co-exist.